# end() expects parameter 1 to be array - php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm retrieving the email list from a `MySQL` database along side with the IDs of the users it gets something like this

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [Email] => email1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [Email] => email2 ) 
)
```

and while trying to test for the value of the last email "email2" I used

```
end(end($array_sample));
```

this used to work on my old server running `PHP` 5.0 and stopped at the new one running `PHP` 5.6

Was there something I did wrong or is it a php version?
I basically changed the whole approach to get the site to do what it was meant to do any how, but I still would like to learn about the `end(end(array))` issue.

Comment: When you say stopped working? Is there an error, does it return anything? [The PHP.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) says this functions exists in PHP 4, 5, and 7 - so it's not a version issue.

Comment: yes, it says end() expects parameter 1 to be array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`end()` function needs to get array by reference, so it can't be a result of other function, because you get following error:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

To avoid it assign result of inner `end()` to variable and then use `end()` on this variable:

```
$tmp = end($array);
$result = end($tmp);
```

And you probably don't get any error in previous version of `PHP` due to `error_reporting` set to quiet them.

According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting):

> Prior to PHP 5.4.0 **E_STRICT** was not included within **E_ALL**, so you
>   would have to explicitly enable this kind of error level in PHP <
>   5.4.0.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, your code [should had never worked](https://3v4l.org/s96tX):

> Only variables should be passed by reference

As [documentation](http://Only%20variables%20should%20be%20passed%20by%20reference) explains:

> This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the
>   function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a
>   function returning an array because only actual variables may be
>   passed by reference.

What has changed is the severity of the error. It has been a fatal error, a strict standards notice and a regular notice. Between 4.3.0 and 5.0.4 is just failed silently.

Most likely the error went unnoticed until you upgraded and an actual error message was triggered.

Comment: Sorry for the ninja editing. I believe the information provided in the answer is fully correct now.

Answer (score 1):

You have an end within another end, the inner one returns last element of array, the outer one is expecting an array not a single value

Comment: yes, but if you see the array I have is a couple arrays nested within an array